# Text modified by innerHTML won't stay visible

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a function that is supposed to display a message in a P element if conditions are met. The function runs fine but the text that is sent to 'output1' appears briefly when you press the button and then disappears. I have tried putting the JS in the head and in the body but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Any ideas? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<p id="output1"><p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function logicProcess() {
    // alert('function launched');
    if(document.getElementById('q1Y').checked || document.getElementById('q2Y').checked || document.getElementById('q3Y').checked) {
        document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Sorry, you don't qualify for our shared ownership properties";
        }
    else {
        document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "You may qualify for our shared ownership scheme. Please complete the registration form.";
        }
}       
</script>
```

Comment: Does the button also submit a form (or perform some other navigation)?

Comment: Two words: prevent default

Answer (score 4):

The reason the innerHTML is not staying visible is because there is some type of onclick method that is resetting the form. If that is true edit your onclick method like so:

```
onClick="function();return false;"
```

The change in here is the ;return false;

Answer (score 0):

You haven't show us how you are calling that function, but the odds are that you are doing so in response to a form's submit button being pressed.

This will modify the DOM, and then submit the form, which will cause a new page to be loaded.

You need to cancel the default behaviour of the form to stop it being submitted.

```
function logicProcess(evt) {
    // All your other code
    evt.preventDefault();
}
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', logicProcess);
```

Comment: Ah ok. It's being called by:

    <button onclick="logicProcess()">Am I eligible?</button>

So I need to cancel the default behavior of the submit button?

Comment: I solved this issue by adding 'type="button"' into the button element. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using input type submit, so the meaning of submit button is to submit the form and reload it, that's why your output is not holding your inner html.
change it to

```
<input type="button" />
```